# Thread synchronisation using semaphores

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, semaphore, thread-synchronization

This was an interview question , any help would be appreciated

How do you synchronize two threads, out of which one increments a value and the the other displays it ( P.S. the thread which displays the value must only display a value when its a new value )

Ex : `int x = 5;`

`T1` : increments it to 6

`T2` : must display 6 ( only once ) and must display it again when it becomes 7

I answered that I would use a semaphore something like:

```
int c=0; // variable that I used to synchronize

// In T1
if( c = 0 )
{
   c++;
   x++; // value that is incremented
}

// in T2
if( c == 1 )
{
   cout<<x;
   c--;
}
```

He then asked what would you do if there's a context switch from thread `T1` to `T2` after setting c to 1 but before incrementing x ( As in that case it would enter P2 before incrementing x )

I couldn't answer this part. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice exercise.

You haven't specified the `c++` tag in the question, but the question itself contains `cout<<x`, so you were probably interviewing for a C++ position. Despite that, I'm going to answer in Java since this is an interview question and language shouldn't matter much as long as I avoid using anything too specific to Java.

As your interviewer pointed out, the synchronization has to happen in both directions:

- The printing thread must wait for the incrementing thread to finish its job
- The incrementing thread must wait for the printing thread to finish its job

So we need something to let us know that the printer is done (so the incrementer can run), and another to let us know that the incrementer is done. I used two semaphores for that:

[Working version on Ideone](https://ideone.com/CPXDXY)

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

class IncrementDemo {
    static int x = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Semaphore incrementLock = new Semaphore(0);
        Semaphore printLock = new Semaphore(0);

        Thread incrementer = new Thread(() -> {
            for(;;) {
                incrementLock.acquire(); //Wait to be allowed to increment
                x++;
                printLock.release(); //Allow the printer to print
            }
        });

        Thread printer = new Thread(() -> {
            for (;;) {
                incrementLock.release(); //Let the incrementer to its job
                printLock.acquire(); //Wait to be allowed to print
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        });

        incrementer.setDaemon(false); //Keep the program alive after main() exits
        printer.setDaemon(false);

        incrementer.start(); //Start both threads
        printer.start();
    }

}
```

(I removed the try/catch blocks around `acquire` for readability).

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
...
```

Comment: This is wrong, at least with [pthread under the hood](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) (which I believe applies to Java as well): `If a thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex which is unlocked, undefined behavior results.` And busy loops may or may not be wrong depending on how memory barriers and other optimizations work (in Java or C++). Anyway the correct answer is conditional variables.

Comment: @freakish AFAIK both Java and `pthread` *Semaphores* (as opposed to *mutexes*) can be "released" and "acquired" by different threads. The busy loop code (which obviously is only for the sake of example, and no one should use) uses `volatile` booleans and `x`, which created a "happens-before" relationship in Java (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html)

Comment: Shouldn't the incrementLock.release() be after the print statement in thread 2

Comment: @user9355495 If both semaphores start with 0, and both threads start by acquiring a permit, they'll both wait indefinitely. You could move the `acquire` after the print, but you'd have to initialize the semaphore to 1.

Comment: Thank you man, this question was asked again in Intel. I answered it this time :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic use case for a *condition variable* with the slight hitch that the value can easily update more than once in thread 1 before thread 2 runs to handle it:

```
// In some scope common to both threads
int c_ = 0; // variable
std::mutex mutex_();
std::condition_variable cond_();

// Thread 1
{ 
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    ++c_;
}
cond_.notify_one();

// Thread 2
{ 
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock( mutex_ );
    int cLocal = c_;
    while ( !done ) { 
        cond_.wait( lock, [] { return c_ != cLocal; } );
        while ( cLocal++ < c_ ) 
            ... // Display new *local* value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problems:

There are 2 main problems with parallel code in general.

**1. Atomicity**

The smallest granularity in code are in fact not the single operations like `i++`, but the underlying assembly-instructions. Therefore every operation, which involves a write, may not be called from multiple threads. (this differs heavily on your target architecture, but x86 is in contrast to arm64 very restrictive)

But luckily c++ provides the `std::atomic` operations, which give you a nice plattform independent way to modify variables from multiple threads.

**2. Consistency**

Both the compiler and the processor are allowed to reorder any instruction as long the consistency of the **local** thread is preserved. So what does this mean?

Take a look at your first thread

```
if( c = 0 )
{
   c++;
   x++; // value that is incremented
}
```

You have 3 operations `c == 0`, `c++` and `x++`. Both increments do not depend from each other, hence the compiler would be allowed to swap them. At runtime the core may reorder them too, leaving you in very vague situation. In a sequential world this is perfectly fine and improves the overall performance (unless it leads to security holes like meltdown). Unfortunately neither the compiler or the cpu recognize parallel code, therefore any optimization may break your parallel program.

But once again, c++ provides a built-in solution for this problem called `std::memory_order`, which enforces are specific consistency-model.

### Solutions:

**Simple mutex:** 
A mutex is a simple, but powerfull tool. It solves the problems with Atomicity and Consistency by providing so called critical sections, which prevent parallel execution. This means, that in the given example the if-clause in both threads are sequential and will never be executed in parallel.
The implementation works, but has a flaw. If one of the threads is very slow, the other one will waste a lot of cpu-time by continous checking the `newValue` flag.

```
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mutex;
int value = true;
bool newValue = false;

void producer_thread() {
   while(true) {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mutex);
        if (newValue == false) {
            value++;
            newValue = true;
        }
   }
}

void consumer_thread() {
   while(true) {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mutex);
        if (newValue == true) {
            std::cout << value;
            newValue = false;
        }
   }
}
```

**Condition Variable**:

A condition variable is basically just a "wait-for-notify"-construct. You can block the current execution by calling `wait` until an other thread calls `notify`. This implementation would be the go-to scenario.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cond;
int value = true;
bool newValue = false;

void producer() {
   while(true) {
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mutex);

        while (newValue == true) {
            cond.wait(ul);
        }

        value++;
        newValue = true;
        cond.notify_all();
   }
}

void consumer() {
   while(true) {
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mutex);

        while (newValue == false) {
            cond.wait(ul);
        }

        std::cout << value;
        newValue = false;
        cond.notify_all();
   }
}
```